# How does one use nested functions / Lambdas in Dart?

Tags: dart

C++ allows lambdas within functions.

```
int main() {
    // This declares a lambda, which can be called just like a function
    auto print_message = [](std::string message) 
    { 
        std::cout << message << "\n"; 
    };

    // Prints "Hello!" 10 times
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        print_message("Hello!"); 
    }
}
```

How does one achieve the same in Dart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

Nested function:

```
void main() {

  void print_message(var message) {
    print(message + '\n');
  }

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    print_message("Hello!");
  }
}
```

Lambda:

If your function is very short and can be represented in just one line, then you can use a lambda:

```
void main() {
  print_message(var message) => print(message + '\n');

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    print_message("Hello!");
  }
}
```

The lambda version is just more concise notation.

In the above version, the lambda has no return type as it is simply printing the value and returns nothing. If you want your lambda to return something, just specify the return type as well:

```
void main() {
  String addNewLine(var message) => message + '\n';

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    print(addNewLine("Hello!"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, the closest corresponding code would be:

```dart
import "dart:io" show stdout;
int main() {
  // Variable declaration, function value ("lambda") assigned to it.
  var printMessage = (String message) {
    stdout..write(message)..write("\n");
  };

  // Prints "Hello!" 10 times
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printMessage("Hello!"); 
  }
}
```

Declaring a variable containing a function value like this is not how it would normally be done in Dart, though, because you can declare local functions:

```dart
int main() {
  // Function declaration.
  void printMessage(String message) {
    print(message);
  }
  // Prints "Hello!" 10 times
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printMessage("Hello!"); 
  }
}
```

Then there are no "lambda"s involved.

Dart generally doesn't use the word "lambda", but it is occasionally used about function values. A function value is more often called a "closure" (even though, in this particular case, it doesn't "close" over any variables), or just a "function value".